# ActiveRecord Query for many to many association

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, active-record

I have two Models in my Rails 6 / PostgreSQL application which have a many to many relation; `Car` and `Driver`. The goal is to get all records (Cars) which have no association at all (Drivers). At the moment this is done using Ruby (2.6.3) like this:

```
result = []
Car.all.each do |car|
  result << car.id if car.drivers.empty?
end
```

Is there an ActiveRecord expression which avoids instantiating each record?

Comment: Have a look at the [ActiveRecord Query Interface](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

Answer (score 1):

To produce the set of records only in `cars`, but not in `drivers`, you perform a left outer join, then exclude the records you don't want from the right side via a where clause.

In Rails 6 you do this in this way:

```rb
Car.left_outer_joins(:drivers).where(car_drivers: { id: nil })
```

Take a look at this article: [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/). It may help you figure out how to do some queries.

Aside from this, a good way to iterate over an array to select some elements according to a condition is to use the [`select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) method. Using `select` your code would be like this:

```rb
result = Car.all.select { |car| car.drivers.empty? }
```

But that is not the way to go here, I'm just showing how to use `select`.

Also, if you want only the `id` from the cars, you can add `pluck(:id)` at the end of the query. This is going to get only the `id` field from the database. Or you just use the method `ids` but the `pluck` method works for any field.